# Inject dependency based on parameter in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, dependency-injection, akka, guice

I keep track of a list of service providers in the database for a `consumerId`.

I have a `SchedulerActor` that creates `TaskActor` for each service provider enabled for the `consumerId`.

I want to inject an implementation of `ServiceProvider` to  `TaskActor`s for each service provider in the list. There can be different implementations of `ServiceProvider`.

```
interface ServiceProvider {
    void processRequest(Request request);
}

class SchedulerActor {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Object consumerId) throws Exception {
         List<String> serviceProvidersList = getFromDatabase((String) consumerId);
         for (String serviceProviderStr : serviceProvidersList) {

              //serviceProviderStr could be "ServiceProvider1" or "ServiceProvider2" 
              ServiceProvider serviceProvider = getServiceProviderFromStr(serviceProviderStr); 

              ActorRef r = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(TaskActor.class, serviceProvider));
              getContext().watch(r);
              routees.add(new ActorRefRoutee(r));

         }
         router = new Router(new BroadcastRoutingLogic(), routees);
         router.route(message, getSelf());
     }
}

class TaskActor {
    private final ServiceProvider serviceProvider;
    public TaskActor(ServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) {
        if (message instanceof Request) {
            serviceProvider.processRequest((Request)message);
        }
    }
}
```

1. What goes inside `getServiceProviderFromStr(String)` to achieve this?
2. I don't want to add `switch` or `if else` statements to return the required implementation.
3. Can I supply Provider Bindings at runtime, passing the string to the provider object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another way to use same named binding instead of proposed @Assisted

```
@Inject 
public Injector injector;
...
ServiceProvider s = injector.getInstance(Key.get(Parent.class, Names.named(serviceName)));
```

where classes bound in configure():

```
bind(ServiceProvider.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Name1")).to(Child1.class);
bind(ServiceProvider.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Name2")).to(Child2.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Guice AssistedInject](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject), namely the [FactoryModuleBuilder](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html) to add to the TaskActor constructor a String parameter for a service name and use this parameter for injecting of a ServiceProvider with @Named annotation:

1. Define in the module a factory interface:

   ```
   public interface TaskActorFactory{
       TaskActor create(String serviceName);
   }
   ```
2. In the module **configure** method install the factory and register services binding:

   ```
   protected void configure() {
       bind(ServiceProvider.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("serviceA")).to(ServiceA.class);
       bind(ServiceProvider.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("serviceB")).to(ServiceB.class);
       bind(ServiceProvider.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("serviceC")).to(ServiceC.class);
       install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
           .implement(TaskActor.class, TaskActor.class)
           .build(TaskActorFactory.class));
    }
   ```
3. Implement TaskActor:

   ```
   @Inject 
   class TaskActor extends UntypedActor {

       public static Props props(String serviceName) {
           return Props.create(TaskActor.class, ()->new TaskActor(serviceName));
       }

       private final ServiceProvider serviceProvider;

       public TaskActor(Injector injector, @Assisted String serviceName) {
           serviceProvider = injector.getInstance(Key.get(ServiceProvider.class, Names.named(serviceName)));
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
4. Create TaskActor from SchedulerActor

   ```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Object consumerId) throws Exception {
        List<String> serviceProvidersList = getFromDatabase((String) consumerId);
        for (String serviceProviderStr : serviceProvidersList) {
            ActorRef r = getContext().actorOf(TaskActor.props(serviceProviderStr));
            getContext().watch(r);
            routees.add(new ActorRefRoutee(r));
        }
        ...
    }
   ```

   }

Comment: I'm missing something here. How do I use `ServiceProviderFactory` to get the implementation that I require without having to call `createServiceA()` or `createServiceB()` or `createServiceC()` specifically?

Comment: The solution does not fit to dynamic service provider injection, so I rewrote the whole answer. I think now the whole picture is more clear (also for me).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `switch` of `if else`, I thought you have to use reflection to do it, where `serviceProviderStr` is the class name.

```
    private ServiceProvider getServiceProviderFromStr(String serviceProviderClassName){
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(serviceProviderClassName);
            if(!ServiceProvider.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument is not a ServiceProvider class.");
            }
            Class<? extends ServiceProvider> serviceProviderClass = (Class<? extends ServiceProvider>) clazz;
            return serviceProviderClass.newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return null;
    }
```

Remember, you can get the class name by calling `AnyClass.class.getName();`.